# CUDA: Is this the correct use of shared memory?

Tags: cuda, gpu-shared-memory

I have the following CUDA kernel:

```
__global__ void combine_kernel(const uint64_t* __restrict__ d_D1,unsigned int hashedFrameNumber)
{
    //1D GRID OF 1D BLOCKS
    int tid = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
    // SIZE = 2118760
    if (tid < 2118760) 
    {
     
      __shared__ uint64_t d_D11[10];
 
      for(int i = threadIdx.x; i < 10; i++)
      {
       d_D11[i] = d_D1[i];    
      }
      __syncthreads();
      
      //POINT A
      //check if d_D1 is unshuffled
      if(tid == SIZE-1)
      {
        printf("%llx \n",d_D1[0]);
        printf("%llx \n",d_D1[1]);
        printf("%llx \n",d_D1[2]);
        printf("%llx \n",d_D1[3]);
        printf("%llx \n",d_D1[4]);
        printf("%llx \n",d_D1[5]);
        printf("%llx \n",d_D1[6]);
        printf("%llx \n",d_D1[7]);
        printf("%llx \n",d_D1[8]);
        printf("%llx \n",d_D1[9]);
        printf("\n\n");    
      }
      
      //POINT B
      //check if shared d_D11 is unshuffled
      if(tid == SIZE-1)
      {
        printf("%llx \n",d_D11[0]);
        printf("%llx \n",d_D11[1]);
        printf("%llx \n",d_D11[2]);
        printf("%llx \n",d_D11[3]);
        printf("%llx \n",d_D11[4]);
        printf("%llx \n",d_D11[5]);
        printf("%llx \n",d_D11[6]);
        printf("%llx \n",d_D11[7]);
        printf("%llx \n",d_D11[8]);
        printf("%llx \n",d_D11[9]);
        printf("\n\n");    
      }
      
     curandState randState;
     curand_init(hashedFrameNumber, 0, 0, &randState);
        
     if(threadIdx.x == 0)
     {       
      for (unsigned int i = 9; i > 0; i--)
      {
       size_t j = (unsigned int) (((curand(&randState) / 32768)*(i+1)) % 10);
       uint64_t t0 = d_D11[j];
       d_D11[j] = d_D11[i];
       d_D11[i] = t0;     
      }
     }
     __syncthreads();

     //POINT C
     //check if d_D1 is shuffled
      if(tid == SIZE-1)
      {
        printf("%llx \n",d_D1[0]);
        printf("%llx \n",d_D1[1]);
        printf("%llx \n",d_D1[2]);
        printf("%llx \n",d_D1[3]);
        printf("%llx \n",d_D1[4]);
        printf("%llx \n",d_D1[5]);
        printf("%llx \n",d_D1[6]);
        printf("%llx \n",d_D1[7]);
        printf("%llx \n",d_D1[8]);
        printf("%llx \n",d_D1[9]);
        printf("\n\n");    
      }


     __syncthreads();
     
    }
}
```

What happens is that, **when I check if `d_D11` is unshuffled at `POINT B`, it is unshuffled if `tid` is between 0 and 31, otherwise is shuffled**, so what am I doing wrong? Is that the correct way of using the shared memory?

`d_D1` contains 10 elements. I just want to pass the 10 elements of array `d_D1` to the shared array `d_D11`, then shuffle the shared array and use it.

Answer (score 2):

You need a `__syncthreads()` barrier before the shuffling code to prevent the previous `printf()`s to print shuffled or partially shuffled values, and again before `POINT C` to ensure the shuffling has finished by the time the result gets printed.

Aside from this correctness issues, your code unnecessarily initializes some elements multiple times.

Initialize your shared memory like this, assuming your blocks are one-dimensional and have at least 10 threads each:

```
__shared__ uint64_t d_D11[10];
unsigned int tidx = threadIdx.x;

if (tidx < 10) {
    d_D11[tidx] = d_D1[tidx];    
}
__syncthreads();
```

If your shared array may have more elements than there are threads, you can use the following idiom:

```
const int N = ...
__shared__ uint64_t d_D11[N];

for(int i = threadIdx.x; i < N; i += blockDim.x)
    d_D11[i] = d_D1[i];    
}
__syncthreads();
```

Comment: The block is one-dimensional and has 10 values, so I guess your first code is right, but what about the shuffle? I do not get the right result with the printf

Comment: Hi, I had already tried with __syncthreads, I just forgot to include it in the code, but still does not work. Is it if(threadIdx.x == 0) right when doing the shuffle? At point B I got the array d_D11 shuffled when it should be unshuffled, at point C is shuffled as it should be

Comment: Updated again. Thanks talonmies for pointing out the issue by editing the question.